# SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit consuming memory

Tags: sql-server-2019

Yesterday I was going over some scripts and notes from a class and noticed that queries were a lot slower. Queries that took 0 ms of cpu time and 10 ms of elapsed time before were taking over 10 seconds. Task Manager showed that SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit was running and using 5 GB out of 8 GB of my memory. I stopped running queries but it went on for hours until dropped down to 2 GB and went on until
I shut it down around 10 pm. This morning SQL Server Windows NT- 64 Bit was using
a few hundred MB of memory until I ran a stored procedure. As you can see in the picture it shot up to over 4 GB of memory and staying at it. I know for sure that this happens a lot but never thought there was a possibility that it was caused by something I ran. If I end the task, I lose the connection. If I restart my computer, it will restart as well, I tested a couple of times. What is really happening and What should I do? [Screenshot of Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIZvD.png)

Comment: SQL Server uses all the available memory it can get **by design**. You can change this in SSMS > Server Properties > Memory.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? It looks like this is a desktop/workstation and not a dedicated SQL Server? It's good practice to always set the max memory for SQL Server - a rule of thumb is 8-10% less than total ram on a dedicated server and more on a desktop or shared resource server.

Comment: At a guess, a poor query plan is causing a table to fill up the buffer pool memory, which by default is as much memory as it can get its hands on.

Comment: It was making all other queries so slow. And also I wanted to understand what was really happening and why. Looks like you all suggest that I change maximum server memory which I never changed so it is at default which is way more than what I have. So I changed it to 3 GB and ran the same stored procedure and executed. SQL Server was using about 700 MB of memory and shot up to 2.85 GB. So that's good. Now it stays at that level for a long time. How do I bring it down to normal level? Not all but some other queries are taking longer to execute.

Comment: @gsong Set a reasonable maximum for memory usage in Server Properties and then restart the SQL Server service. There are ways to make SQL Server release memory back to the OS without restarting but they're unreliable and intended for production use, whereas restarting the service on your workstation is the most straightforward solution.

Comment: @Dai That's what I wanted to know. I thought there might be a way to free memory back to the OS like FREEPROCCACHE. I changed max server memory and so far so good. Thank you for the suggestions!